# Can't Submit ModelForm using CBVs

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use ModelForms and CBVs to handle them, but I am facing trouble especially while submitting my form. Here's my code.

**forms.py**

```py
from django import forms

from .models import Volunteer


class NewVolunteerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Volunteer
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

from .forms import NewVolunteerForm


class NewVolunteerView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'website/join.html'
    form_class = NewVolunteerForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print('Submitting')
        form.save()
        return HttpResponse('DONE')
```

**join.html**

```py
{% extends 'website/_base.html' %}
{% block title %}Join Us{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}

    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

The form is getting displayed correctly with no issues at all, but when I fill it in and press the submit button it simply re-rendered the form and doesn't submit it at all.

Comment: What do you get when you specify `<form action="{% url 'name-of-some-view' %}"  method="post">`? with `name-of-some-view` the name of the view for the class-based view `NewVolunteerView`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, Same issue, I have two image fields when I click submit it simply re renderes the page and resets the images I have selected and indicates them as "This field is required", and as usual nothing gets saved to the database.

Comment: what do you get if you `print(form.errors)` in the `def form_invalid(self, form)` method?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, Nothing is getting printed, I also tried printing something random inside that function as you saw in my code but that didn't run aswell, however I am sure that the form is valid and the post request is getting made because in the console it gets shown as [02/Sep/2021 16:51:05] "POST /join/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4331

Comment: can you show the `urls.py`? It looks like you are triggering the wrong view, since a view should either call `form_valid`, or `form_invalid` on a POST request.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed you specified in the form_invalid function, lemme try that

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I found the error by using print(form.errors) in the form_invalid function. The error states my file uploads can't be empty, but they aren't! I am selecting files to upload and when I click submit they become empty!

Comment: ah yes, if you want to submit files as well, you need to specify the `enctype`. This is also listed in the *newbie mistakes*: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NewbieMistakes#Anothercause

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, Well, I wish I knew this 4 hours earlier :D. BTW Thanks a lot! You helped guide me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to my `<form>` element.

The reason was when you have ImageFields or FileFields this attribute should be used.